# Express routes not working as they should

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I have a standard expressroute for this login. Even if req.body.password is incorrect I get redirected to '/login'

```
router.post('/student/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.password = 'password') {
    return res.status(200).redirect('/login')
  } else {
    return res.status(401).redirect('/landingpage')
  }
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be `req.body.password === 'password'`. With `req.body.password = 'password'`, you are making an assignment and it will always resolve to `true`.

Comment: You are using single = in the if statement which results in silent assignment and will always execute the if branch.

Comment: Ah ofcourse! Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the = to === in line two as you are assigning a value with just = and are comparing value with ===

```js
router.post('/student/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.password === 'password') {
    return res.status(200).redirect('/login')
  } else {
    return res.status(401).redirect('/landingpage')
  }
})
```